# Frequency distribution of words and phrases

Tags: python, performance

I need to find a way how to create a frequency distribution out of multilple text files. In fact I am asked to check the number of times a word or a phrase occurs in a txt file. The code should check from a predefinded list (my list is called l1) how often this word or phrase can be found in the doc. My output should look like the following:

```
UNIQA VERSICHERUNGEN:31.12.2008
acceptance  2
acceptance credit   0
acceptance sampling 0
accounting principles   10
accounting principles board 0
additional  30
corporate   36
corporate bond  0
corporate finance   0
corporate governance    15
```

My code looks as follows. It does what it should do, but it is very slow (takes about a minute per file to process).

```
    from collections import Counter
    from itertools import chain
    import re
    import os
    import glob
    from nltk.tokenize import *
    import nltk
    from os import listdir

    def removeNonAscii(s): return "".join(i for i in s if ord(i)<128)

    def read_textfile(filename):
        # Reads the entire content of FILENAME and returns a non Ascii letters cleaned string
        infile = open(filename) 
        contents = removeNonAscii(infile.read())
        infile.close()
        return contents

    def list_textfiles(directory, min_file_size):
        # Creates a list of all files stored in DIRECTORY ending on '.txt'
        textfiles = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, name)
            if os.stat(filename).st_size > min_file_size:
                textfiles.append(filename)
    return textfiles

def remove_punctuation1(text):
    # Removes all punctuation and conotation from the string and returns a 'plain' string
    punctuation = '®©™€â´‚³©¥ã¼•ž®è±äüöž!@#Â“§$%^*()î_+€$=¿{”}[]:«;"»\â¢|<>,.?/~`0123456789'
    for sign in punctuation:
        text = text.replace(sign, "")
    return text

def remove_punctuation2(text):
    # Removes all punctuation and conotation from the string and returns a 'plain' string
    punctuation2 = '-&'
    for sign in punctuation2:
        text = text.replace(sign, " ")
    return text

filepath_dict = "H:/MA Daske/Wordlists/IFRS.txt" # input filepath for the used wordlist (here external accounting dictionary)
directory = "H:/Converted Text/EU0_OM0_FY2001" # directory of the text files to be processed
min_file_size = 90000

l1 = remove_punctuation2(removeNonAscii(read_textfile(filepath_dict))).lower().split('\n') # externally created word/expression list

vocabulary_dict  = {k:0 for k in l1} 

for filename in list_textfiles(directory, min_file_size):
    # inread each report as textfile, match tokenized text with predefined wordlist and count number of occurences of each element of that wordlist
    sample_text = remove_punctuation2(remove_punctuation1(read_textfile(filename).lower())).replace('\n', " ")
    #sample_text = remove_punctuation2(remove_punctuation1(sample_text)).replace('\n', " ")
    sample_text = ' '.join(sample_text.split())
    splitted = sample_text.split()
    c = Counter()
    c.update(splitted)
    #print(c)
    outfile = open(filename[:-4] + '_output' + '.txt', mode = 'w')
    string = str(filename)
    string_print = string[string.rfind('/')+1:string.find('-')] + ':' + string[-6:-4] + '.' + string[-8:-6] + '.' + string[-12:-8]
    samples = set(sample_text.split())
    for k in vocabulary_dict:
        spl = k.split()
        ln = len(spl)
        if ln > 1:
            check = re.findall(r'\b{0}\b'.format(k),sample_text)
            if check:
                vocabulary_dict[k] += len(check)
        elif k in samples:
            vocabulary_dict[k] += c[k]
    outfile.write(string_print + '\n')
    # line wise write each entry of the dictionary to the corresponding outputfile including comapany name, fiscal year end and tabulated frequency distribution
    for key, value in sorted( vocabulary_dict.items() ):
        outfile.write( str(key) + '\t' + str(value) + '\n' )
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE! Indentation seems to be wrong, could you please have a look and fix ?

Answer (score 2):

### Use consistent naming

```
removeNonAscii(s) -> remove_non_ascii(n)
```

### Use with

```
def read_textfile(filename):
    # Reads the entire content of FILENAME and returns a non Ascii letters cleaned string
    with open(filename) as f:
        return removeNonAscii(f.read())
```

### Merge similar functions

```
def remove_punctuation1(text):
    # Removes all punctuation and conotation from the string and returns a 'plain' string
    punctuation = '®©™€â´‚³©¥ã¼•ž®è±äüöž!@#Â“§$%^*()î_+€$=¿{”}[]:«;"»\â¢|<>,.?/~`0123456789'
    for sign in punctuation:
        text = text.replace(sign, "")
    return text

    def remove_punctuation(text):
    # Removes all punctuation and conotation from the string and returns a 'plain' string
    punctuation2 = '-&'
    for sign in punctuation2:
        text = text.replace(sign, " ")
    return text
```

Should become

```
def remove_punctuation(text):
    # Removes all punctuation and conotation from the string and returns a 'plain' string
    punctuation2 = '-&'+'®©™€â´‚³©¥ã¼•ž®è±äüöž!@#Â“§$%^*()î_+€$=¿{”}[]:«;"»\â¢|<>,.?/~`0123456789'
    for sign in punctuation2:
        text = text.replace(sign, " ")
    return text
```

### Use docstrings

```
def read_textfile(filename):
    """
    Reads the entire content of FILENAME and 
    returns a non Ascii letters cleaned string.
    """
    with open(filename) as f:
        return removeNonAscii(f.read())
```

### Avoid one-two letter variable names, prefer longer ones

```
l1 -> words_to_check
```

Answer (score 2):

- It would make a lot more sense to read files one line at a time (less strain on the runtime, allocating only a small string at a time might be a lot easier / efficient than trying to work with a whole file at once).
- It's better to leave out particularities such as input file location. Instead read them in from command line (with possibly some sensible defaults).
- Your `remove_punctuation2` has two problems: numbers in function names are considered bad practice (how is this function different from `remove_punctuation1`? why not reflect this difference in the name?). Another problem is that what it does could be done with a lot less effort with a regular expression. Look at `re.sub` for details.
- Why go into so much trouble creating `string_print`? It seems like it could be less opaque to the reader what the result should look like if you used a template or named the pieces of strings you combined to produce this string.
- I don't see where are you use NLTK library? Did you need to import it?